# Parsing CSV file on Java to extract String

Tags: java, csv, parsing, jtextfield

On Java Ive make a simple program with search bar. Ive also a CSV File 'file.csv' that contains this:

```html
"ID","FIRSTNAME","LASTNAME"
"JM1","Jean","Martial"
"AD1","Audrey","Dubois"
"BX1","Bertrand","Xavier"
```

I can open the file on Java with this line.

```
String file = "C:\\file.csv";
```

To verify if file exists I use this line.

```
if(new File(file).exists()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Fichier ouvert succes");
}
```

Now I want to parse the file to extract **AD1** and display true if exist or false if not exists. Ive declared **Scanner** for this, but i dont know how to setup for this.

```html
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
  scanner = new Scanner(new File(file));
  scanner.useDelimiter(coma_delimiter);
  while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    String s1= scanner.next();
    System.out.print(s1 +"   ");
    if(s1.equals(search_field.getText())) {
      System.out.print("OKOK");
    } else {
      System.out.println("NOK");
    }
  }


} catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
  fe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  scanner.close();
}
```

Here the **search_field** is a JTextField.

Comment: "I can open the file on Java with this line. `String file = "C:\\file.csv";`" - no, that is just a string and doesn't open the file at all. Besides that, if you are able to read the file line by line then what's the problem with checking whether the line _contains_ ADB1? (Note that you don't want to check using `equals()` but `contains()`). If you need to do more then it might be better to look for a CSV parser library and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading your file line by line. What you are actually supposed to do is get a line, split it, remove the double quotes and compare to your string. Or you can wrap your input string in a double quote and just compare with the string after splitting. For this try the following code:

```
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
  scanner = new Scanner(new File(file));

  String s1 = null;
  String id= null;
  String[] tempArr = null;
  String searchStr = "\""+search_field.getText()+"\"";
  System.out.print("searchStr = " + searchStr );

  while(scanner.hasNext()) { // While there are more lines in file 
    s1= scanner.nextLine();
    tempArr = s1.split(","); // use coma_delimiter instead coma_delimiter if coma_delimiter=","
    id = (tempArr != null && tempArr.length > 0? tempArr[0] : null);
    System.out.print("ID = " + id);

    if(id != null && id.equals(searchStr)) {
      System.out.print("OKOK");
      break; // quit the loop searchStr is found
    } else {
    System.out.println("NOK");
    }
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
 fe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your script works. Ive changed you System.out.println by Alert message. And when I verify "BX1" exists. Ive 4 alert. The three beginning alert are FALSE and the fourth is TRUE. How to get directly TRUE on the first ALERT if its true. And FALSE directly if its FALSE

Comment: I just added `id != null &&` in the if condition as id can be null. This is to avoid null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html) instead as this is designed to work with csv file, straight from their page is the below example

```
Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String lastName = record.get("Last Name");
    String firstName = record.get("First Name");
}
```

where "Last Name" and "First Name" are all column names.
This way you can clearly check on which column your string is.

Maven dependency below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can't import CSVRecord and CSVFormat. Why? please.

Comment: If you are using maven i have included the dependency on my answer else you need to download the jar file in their site

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the stream API to process each line individually. It may also have methods that would make this more elegant than my answer.

```
final String ENCL = "\"";
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    Map<String, List<String>> ans = stream.map(s -> {
        String[] split = s.split(",");
        if(split.length > 2) {
            for(int i = 0; i < split.length; ++i) {
                if(split[i].length() >= 2) {
                    if(split[i].startsWith(ENCL)) {
                        split[i] = split[i].substring(1);
                    }
                    if(split[i].endsWith(ENCL)) {
                        split[i] = split[i].substring(0, split[i].length()-1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return split;
    })
    .filter(s->s.length > 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s-> Arrays.asList(s[1], s[2])));

    // do what you will with ans
    return ans.containsKey("AD1");
}
catch(IOException ex) {
    // do what you will
}
```